# iStack for iPad

Tags: discussion, apps, ipad

iStack iPad currently isn't available on the appstore, it's in development as is getting towards the end of the first version.

**I'm now *starting* to look for beta testers, you will need an iPad device, any iOS version will do, please post an answer to this question if you want to volunteer, I won't start testing immediately. And I'll be looking for general feedback/problems as well as bugs and crashes.**

Each column now has an edit button where the sites can be rearranged and moved from favourites to non favourites and this is persistent between app launches, moving a site in one column moves it in all of them.

[image]

Printing Functionality all implemented and working, thanks to systempuntoout's [stackprinter.com](http://www.stackprinter.com/) works with AirPrint, which means this app will be iOS 4.2 minimum.
[image]

Current features (well some are "features"):

- 3 columns
- Email link to question, open in safari and copy link actions
- History for both questions and sites visited
- In app notification (red bar at the top) when a new site makes it into beta.
- StackPrinter in the app, without needing safari, and AirPrint functionality.
- Facebook Intergration
- Post owner pages, with associated accounts.
- Shrink the bottom dock so there's just the text.
- Add questions to local favourites.
- Caches the last downloaded list of questions for each site, so you can look at questions while loading the latest, including after restarting the app.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, please only use the [app] tag for apps that are released, not discussions.

Comment: sorry, I won't do it again :)

Comment: @Jonathan feel free to link StackPrinter

Comment: This looks really nice.  Can't wait to see it in person!

Comment: Thanks, its getting there, quite slowly though. And I need to convince someone to lend their iPad so I can test on it, that or save up and buy one.

Comment: Im willing to test your app as well dude. I have a few ideas

Comment: If you still need Beta testers, I am up for the Job :)!

Comment: Should this not be removed as this is not in the app store and 2 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

I'm willing to volunteer for the Beta. An iPad app for StackExchange is most definitely needed.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep you in mind, and contact you when I testing can start. There has been a slight delay to my original plans

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling that Apple will slap you on the wrist with this design/block your submission, due to your site navbar looking identically to the home bar introduced in 4.2 (for the iPad anyways).

Comment: The background for that is using an Apple documented texture (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIColor/scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor) it is intended for scroll views of which the nav bar is. (the home bar is actually darker and has a higher contrast than that texture) so it should be fine as many apps use it.

Comment: I sure hope that's true. I have every reason to believe you, I've just never seen a non-traditional black backed, grey icon standard toolbar before.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be most interested in beta testing iStack.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep you in mind, and contact you when I testing can start. There has been a slight delay to my original plans

Answer (score 1):

I'd be also very interesting to test this app. It seems very useful and helpful for stack-community.

Comment: Thanks, you are added to the list :) It will be while before testing can start.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider me available for test as well.

Comment: Thanks, the earliest possible time I can start is next week, but it likely to be at least 2 weeks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the beta is still open, but I would be willing to test this out. Dying for a nice SE app.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how beta testing works, but I'd be open to testing if it is still open. I'm not a developer either, so I don't know if I even *can* beta test.